# Django form is not valid

Tags: django, forms, django-views, django-forms

I am trying to submit a form and it will not pass as `is_valid` in the view.

The form uses forms.Modelforms which I do not have a lot of experience with.

I checked `{{ form.errors }}` in the template but didn't get anything back.

I appreciate the time and expertise

**Form**

```
class AddSubcategory(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Subcategory
        fields = ['category']

    subcategory_name = forms.CharField(max_length=255)
```

**View**

```
@login_required
@locationed
def add_subcategory(request, location):

    subcat_form = AddSubcategory(request.POST)

    if subcat_form.is_valid():

        submitted_subcat_name = subcat_form.cleaned_data['subcategory_name']

        selected_cat = subcat_form.cleaned_data['category']

            _, was_created = Subcategory.objects.get_or_create(name=submitted_subcat_name, category=selected_cat)


        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('manage_cat_subcat', args=(location.slug,)))
    else:
        cat_form = AddCategory()
        subcat_form = AddSubcategory()
        return render(request, 'inventory/manage_cat_subcat.html', {'location': location,'cat_form': cat_form,'subcat_form':subcat_form})
```

**Template (form)**

```
<form class="form-inline" action="{% url 'add_subcategory' location.slug %}" method="post">

     {% csrf_token %}

            {{subcat_form.category}}

            {{subcat_form.subcategory_name}}

            <button class="btn btn-small" type="submit">Add Subcategory</button>    
        </form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You specify in fields that you need `id, category and name` but you don't put them in your form in your template.

You have only `category and subcategory_name`.

You can add those two elements in your template OR remove them from the fields list.

Also you don't specify an action for your form, you should give the view where the data from your form should be sent.

Comment: Worked great! Thanks for the feedback! (I made edit to my question above based on your feedback)

Comment: Glad it helped! Sometimes django can be too magic and you need to dive in the code.